# How to get sum of weighted valued for count distinct person

Tags: sql, count, sum, distinct, rdbms

I have a sql query that is not giving the expected result:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_cond_num as
          SELECT DISTINCT
          a.age
          ,a.gender
          ,b.concept_id
          ,count(distinct a.person_id) as numpat
          ,round(sum(a.sample_weight)) as w_numpat
          FROM tmp_pat a
          JOIN analytics.aia_tools.dh_t20_medical_histroy_w_hrc b ON a.person_id = b.person_id
          AND a.grp = 1
          GROUP BY
          a.age
          ,a.gender
          ,concept_id
```

I am counting distinct person_id here. I need to count the sample weights for those distinct person_id. Right now w_numpat is summing for duplicate person_id too. How do I just get the sum for the distinct person_id?

Comment: [Why should I tag-my RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: You need a CTE or subquery to clean the data (get one row per person) before you can calculate your averages.

Answer (score 0):

Need to create subquery that contains distinct person results.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_cond_num as
          SELECT DISTINCT
          a.age
          ,a.gender
          ,b.concept_id
          ,count(a.person_id) as numpat
          ,sum(a.sample_weight) as w_numpat
          FROM tmp_pat a
          JOIN (SELECT distinct person_id, concept_id 
          FROM analytics.aia_tools.dh_t20_medical_histroy_w_hrc where first_inpatient_visit_date IS NOT NULL) b 
          ON a.person_id = b.person_id
          AND a.grp = 1
          GROUP BY
          a.age
          ,a.gender
          ,concept_id;
```